# No Such Element Exception(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-15

i'm learning automation and i have exception in my java code. using Intellij IDEA

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "84B7N16401000731");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("app", "C:\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\unlock_apk\\unlock_apk-debug.apk");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
 AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().description(\"Apps\")").click();
    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Speech Morphing\")").click();

    driver.quit();
}
```

and there is the exception message

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Speechmorphing_Auto\build\classes\main;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.appium\java-client\4.0.0\b73316f27bb70d60081429c768cf09a09f6eeece\java-client-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.6.2\f1bc476cc167b18e66c297df599b2377131a8947\gson-2.6.2.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-java\2.53.0\645a24b52c9e5704e900ac755b5800352e981af7\selenium-java-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.2\733db77aa8d9b2d68015189df76ab06304406e50\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\19.0\6ce200f6b23222af3d8abb6b6459e6c44f4bb0e9\guava-19.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\cglib\cglib\3.2.1\e5358fe643ab732ca07b2c0a7bbdd47719cca166\cglib-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-validator\commons-validator\1.5.0\26b98c21975c5caf6bf34bacdeb7183be7a65970\commons-validator-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.4\5fe28b9518e58819180a43a850fbc0dd24b7c050\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\2.53.0\7541a3948c3fb31122ee9633731e8103f3292b0a\selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-edge-driver\2.53.0\9f3da0dfa620ae8cd71afacfdd6ddae5028ce1ea\selenium-edge-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.53.0\5dc655b1999898d2fc3791c649b7355d98629a69\selenium-firefox-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-ie-driver\2.53.0\27b703e9fba9c0f636109cf4bd697c1f208ac825\selenium-ie-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-safari-driver\2.53.0\c80224258a8b702c99f2d7b3847ce89dc1bcd2bd\selenium-safari-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-support\2.53.0\3706aa8a696d1b7938365a41ee7ca46309a0b2d\selenium-support-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-leg-rc\2.53.0\bdabcf672449c588913ae32973dd8f7d54f510de\selenium-leg-rc-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.4\b31526a230871fbe285fbcbe2813f9c0839ae9b0\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\9ce04e34240f674bc72680f8b843b1457383161a\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm\5.0.3\dcc2193db20e19e1feca8b1240dbbc4e190824fa\asm-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.ant\ant\1.9.4\6d473e8653d952045f550f4ef225a9591b79094a\ant-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\7a87d845ad3a155297e8f67d9008f4c1e5656b71\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8.1\3dec9b9c7ea9342d4dbe8c38560080d85b44a015\commons-digester-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\8ad72fe39fa8c91eaaf12aadb21e0c3661fe26d5\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.53.0\eb76ed037ba5a7c11cce11effd0e2175056905ac\selenium-remote-driver-2.53.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\b1b6ea3b7e4aa4f492509a4952029cd8e48019ad\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-exec\1.3\8dfb9facd0830a27b1b5f29f84593f0aeee7773b\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna\4.1.0\1c12d070e602efd8021891cdd7fd18bc129372d4\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna-platform\4.1.0\23457ad1cf75c2c16763330de5565a0e67b4bc0a\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty\3.5.7.Final\811465e6dfc89d7c78d21de6a9747b6046cb5403\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.ant\ant-launcher\1.9.4\334b62cb4be0432769679e8b94e83f8fd5ed395c\ant-launcher-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\58d3be5953547c0019e5704d6ed4ffda3b0c7c66\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Users\amro.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-api\2.53.0\a6105ad5c43dcc02c1cf87250111b0a7f1a7c2e6\selenium-api-2.53.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 3.26 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LHDBICT', ip: '169.254.29.190', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
>   Capabilities [{app=C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=84B7N16401000731, platform=LINUX, desired={app=C:\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk, platformName=Android, deviceName=84B7N16401000731}, platformVersion=6.0.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=Android, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
>   Session ID: 51cac0c2-8741-4fa6-b5a6-7d0e807f8228
>   *** Element info: {Using=-android uiautomator, value=new UiSelector().description("Apps")}
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:67)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(AndroidDriver.java:468)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:21)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters"  It means the ID you used to locate the element on your app is not correct.
Is your app launching when you are running test ?